# Spring Bean depending on initialization of non-Spring class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Say I have some Java class named `SomeClassConfig` in which I want to define a dependency injection like the following;

```
@Configuration
public class SomeClass {

    @Bean
    SomeOtherClass someOtherClass() {
        FactoryClass factory = UtilFactoryClass.getDefaultFactory();
        return factory.create();
    }
}
```

Here `UtilFactoryClass` denotes some library that allows me to create a factory class, which in turn allows me to create an instance of the object I am interested in. My problem is that the above-mentioned default factory is initialized after some time, so I would like for the bean to be instantiated / injected after the instantiation the default `FactoryClass` instance. Is this possible? `UtilFactoryClass` has no knowledge of the Spring Boot framework, and I tried to apply the @DependsOn annotation, but realized it only allows for me to depend on other Beans.
The concrete 'getDefaultFactory' method I am trying to apply is the following: [Link](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/services/resources/KeycloakApplication.html#getSessionFactory--). It is associated to a library named Keycloak. My problem is that the factory obtained from this method is null until a certain point in the life cycle of the application.

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to achieve. Can you explain it a bit better? Do you face any issue?

Comment: Having only this piece of code, normally it should work without any issue. "default factory is initialized after some time" - how is this factory initialized, who takes care of initializing it? isn't it just a normal factory?

Comment: Maybe consider making the `getDefaultFactory()` call blocking until it is ready. This will increase the setup time of the application, but will ensure that all dependents on this instance can use it once the app starts. Or you can return a proxy in `getDefaultFactory()` which will keep failing gracefully until the underlying object is ready. Either way, I doubt spring will help here.

Comment: I have tried to add some description of the specific library I am using (a Keycloak static method).

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeClass {

  @Bean
  SomeOtherClass someOtherClass() { //argument injection also possible
    return factory().create();
  }

  @Bean
  FactoryClass factory() {
    //check/wait for condition e.g.:
    while (!UtilityFactory.isInitialized()) { 
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000); 
        // better: TimeUnit.XXX.sleep(), and even better use an (spring managed) executor
      } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
    }
    return UtilFactoryClass.getDefaultFactory();
  }
}
```

"Let spring manage the factory"!? ;)

For the check/wait part, see: https://www.baeldung.com/java-delay-code-execution

Comment: That is a better idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @xerx593. Sorry for asking about this, but what are your comments trying to imply? That the code is non-mandatory?

Comment: no problem, sorry, get you: It's mandatory for "delay checking", i uncomment ... but you'd have to implement/ensure `(boolean)UtilityFactory.isInitialized()` (*e.g.* as `return getDefaultFactory() != null;`)

Comment: I am not sure if I like the idea of using Thread.sleep() since this seems like it would possibly allow for unintended blocking. But I want to thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: don't worry about blocking (it is a singleton bean), and if you don't have any opportunity "to listen", then you *have to* "poll"!(?) if we go deeper into "keycloak-spring integration", then there seem to be 2 approaches: the high level integration (like [documented at keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_boot_adapter)) or the embedded usage (as outlined [here](https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app) and [here](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/oauth-rest/oauth-authorization-server))